# Finding points at which tangent plane is horizontal

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given the surface: $$ z = 3xy-x^3 - y^3 $$
I found the equation for the tangent line at points (a,b,c) as:
$$
z-c = (3b -3a^2)(x-a) +(3a-3b^2)(y-b) 
$$
using partial derivatives of z with respect to x and y.

My understanding is that in order to find points at which the tangent plane is horizontal the partials $Fx = Fy = 0$

Solving the system of equations I got
$$ 3y-3x^2 = 0 $$
$$ 3x-3y^2 = 0 $$
which give points (0,0) and (1,1). But how do I find the z components? and are these valid points for which the tangent is horizontal?

My understanding was the component z = 1 since the normal vector parallel is (0,0,1).

Comment: "But how do I find z-components?". Well, if $x=y=0$ then $z=0$ and if $x=y=1$ then $z=1$. Now you have the points, right?

Comment: Your equation is not for a tangent line, but for a plane that goes through $(a,b,c)$ and whose normal vector is parallel to the gradient of the function 
$$f(x,y,z)= 3xy-x^2-y^2-z$$
it is only a tangent plane if $f(a,b,c)=0$